# How To Using Dataflow With Only BroadcastBlock And ActionBlock

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, waithandle

This is my first question in SO, i'm new using DataFlow with BroadcastBlock and ActionBlock, i hope i can get solution in here.
Here's the structure.

### Model

```csharp
class SampleModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public object UniqueData { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"Id - {Id}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Success - {Success}");
        sb.AppendLine($"UniqueData - {UniqueData}");
        string tmp = sb.ToString();
        sb.Clear();
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

### DataFlow Logic

```csharp
class CreateDownloadTask
{
    public async Task VeryLongProcess()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Long Process Working..");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            Console.WriteLine("Long Process Done..");
        });
    }

    public async Task CreateSimpleBroadcastX<T>(T data)
    {
        Action<T> process = async model =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working..");
            await VeryLongProcess();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        };


        var broad = new BroadcastBlock<T>(null);

        var action = new ActionBlock<T>(process);

        var dflo = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

        broad.LinkTo(action, dflo);

        await broad.SendAsync(data);

        broad.Complete();

        await action.Completion.ContinueWith(async tsk =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Continue data");
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        Console.WriteLine("All Done");
    }
}
```

### Caller

```csharp
var task = cdt.CreateSimpleBroadcastX<SampleModel>(new SampleModel
{
    UniqueData = cdt.GetHashCode()
});
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
Console.WriteLin("Completed");
```

### I expect the result should be

```
Working..
Long Process Working..
Long Process Done..
Done
Continue data
All Done
Completed
```

### But what i've got is

```
Working..
Long Process Working..
Continue data
All Done
Completed
Long Process Done..
Done
```

This is happen when ther is `async-await` inside of ActionBlock.
Now, the question is, is that possible to make the result as i expected without `WaitHandle` ?

That mean, ActionBlock.Completion will be wait until the `Action` or `Delegate` inside the ActionBlock is complete executed?

Or i'm i doing it wrong with that patter?

Thanks in Advance, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Action<T> process = async model => ...
```

That code creates an `async void` method, which [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). One of the reasons you should avoid `async void` is because it is difficult to know when the method has completed. And this is exactly what is happening: the `ActionBlock<T>` cannot know when your delegate has completed because it is `async void`.

The proper [delegate type for an asynchronous method without a return value that takes a single argument](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) is `Func<T, Task>`:

```
Func<T, Task> process = async model => ...
```

Now that the asynchronous method returns a `Task`, the `ActionBlock` can know when it completes.

Comment: Ah.. i see, thanks a lot it's work now as expected..